# Airflow & Google Drive API - only able to use folders within My Drive, not shared Team folders

Tags: google-drive-api, airflow, airflow-2.x

When attempting to use the `GoogleDriveToGCSOperator` via a Service Account, I am only able to interact with folders I create directly within the `My Drive` path in Drive. If I use a different Team/Shared Drive, I receive errors even though the Team drive has also granted permissions to the Service Account.

```
    upload_gdrive_to_gcs = GoogleDriveToGCSOperator(
        task_id="upload_gdrive_object_to_gcs",
        folder_id="my-folder-id-here",
        file_name="abc.txt",
        bucket_name="gdrive-testbucket",
        object_name="testfile.txt",
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    )
```

This operator for example produces the below error when trying to use the Team drive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gdrive_to_gcs.py", line 126, in execute
    gdrive_hook.download_file(file_id=file_metadata["id"], file_handle=file)
KeyError: 'id'
```

But if I simply switch the `folder_id` to a folder within my own `My Drive` path, it is successful. Both `My Drive` and the shared Team drive are sharing the same access/permissions to the service account.

Has anyone run into this and were able to get these operators to work with the Team drive folders?

Comment: Do you know if `GoogleDriveToGCSOperator` supports Team/Shared Drive? some applications or platforms do not support Team/Shared Drive since it depends on the methods that it's used to make the calls. 

For example, the method [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) does not support the listing of files inside Team/Shared Drive. However, you can use the method [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to list files and folders inside of a Team/Shared Drive.

Comment: thanks @GiselleValladares yes it does, I realized shared drives must include the `drive_id` param in the operator, while My Drive files only require `folder_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interact with files in a team shared drive you must include the `drive_id` param in the operator (which looks like a folder ID at the end of the URL when you are in the root of the shared drive). Otherwise it assumes you are looking for a file in My Drive (which only requires the folder_id)